# Typescript can't find @types/spotify-api in my angular project

Tags: typescript

I installed `@types/spotify-api` and made the following changes to my tsconfig.json

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"types": [
  "spotify-api"
],
```

Typescript can't find `PlaylistTrackResponse` for example. I can't figure out why because it works the same way with types like `@types/node` in other projects. I'm using typescript 3.7.5.

my full tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "spotify-api"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you still need an answer to this since you asked the question quite a while ago but you can get around this by putting:

```
/// <reference types="spotify-api" />
```

at the top of your class and then getting any types like so:

```
SpotifyApi.PlaylistObjectSimplified
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nx Workspace and are facing the same errors after creating a library. Make sure to check `tsconfig.app.json` and remove the `types: []`. It will overrides the global types thing which make SpotifyApi namespace "disappear"

[image: Nx workspace library]